# How do I use TabRows to filter a list of items?

Tags: list, filter, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I have two enums - `Category` (F, H, X) and `Division` (FA...FC, HA...HD, XA...XD) - that I'm using to generate two `TabRow`s: depending on the value of `Category`, the displayed `Division`s will change.

I want these `TabRow`s to act as a filter for my list of matches on two separate screens: Schedule and Scores.

It's *almost* working.

If I'm looking at the list of matches on the Schedule screen and change either Category or Division, nothing changes. But, if I now switch to Scores or come back to Schedule, the filter is applied and I see the correct matches.

How do I get the list to update immediately when I change the values, instead of not refreshing until I change screens?

I've tried using just `LaunchedEffect`, just `SideEffect` and both. I don't see any difference between them, honestly.

P. S. `global.foobar()` is a utility function that updates `global.division` to a default value (either .fa, .ha, .xa) when `global.category` changes.

```
@Composable
fun ScheduleFilters() {
    var selectedCategory by remember { mutableStateOf(global.category) }
    var selectedDivision by remember { mutableStateOf(global.division) }

    val divisions = when (selectedCategory) {
        Categories.womens -> listOf(Divisions.fa, Divisions.fb, Divisions.fc)
        Categories.mens -> listOf(Divisions.ha, Divisions.hb, Divisions.hc, Divisions.hd)
        Categories.mixed -> listOf(Divisions.xa, Divisions.xb, Divisions.xc, Divisions.xd)
    }

    Column {
        TabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = Categories.values().indexOf(selectedCategory),
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
        ) {
            Categories.values().forEach { category ->
                Tab(
                    text = { Text(category.name) },
                    selected = selectedCategory == category,
                    onClick = {
                        global.category = category
                        global.foobar()
                        selectedCategory = global.category
                        selectedDivision = global.division
                    }
                )
            }
        }

        TabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = divisions.indexOf(selectedDivision),
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant
        ) {
            divisions.forEach { division ->
                Tab (
                    text = { Text(division.name) },
                    selected = selectedDivision == division,
                    onClick = {
                        global.division = division
                        selectedDivision = global.division
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScheduleList() {
    var global by remember { mutableStateOf(global) }
    var filteredMatches by remember { mutableStateOf(fullSeasonSchedule) }

//    LaunchedEffect(global) {
//        filteredMatches = fullSeasonSchedule
//            .filter { it.league == global.league }
//            .filter { it.category == global.category }
//            .filter { it.division == global.division }
//            .sortedBy { match -> match.date }
//            .toMutableList()
//    }

    SideEffect {
        filteredMatches = fullSeasonSchedule
            .filter { it.league == global.league }
            .filter { it.category == global.category }
            .filter { it.division == global.division }
            .sortedBy { match -> match.date }
            .toMutableList()
    }

    Column {
        ScheduleFilters()

        LazyColumn {
            items(filteredMatches) { ScheduleRow(match = it) }
        }
    }
}
```